# How can I cancel the rest of a list of commands in Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, job-control

In Bash, occasionally I will type in a [list of commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and only later realize that there is a mistake with some command near the end of the list.  I know that if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it will terminate the currently running command and cancel the rest of the list.  Is there any way to cancel the rest of the list *without* terminating the currently running command?

For example, let's say I have typed something like

```
foo; bar
```

or

```
foo && bar
```

where `foo` is a long-running command that it is very important not to interrupt, and `bar` does something irreversible and unwanted (say, `shutdown -h now` or `rm -rf /`).  While `foo` is still running, is there a general way of telling the shell to let `foo` finish but not to run `bar` afterwards?  (Yes, I could change the permissions on `bar` so that it's not executable, but that's not particularly convenient if `bar` is something like `rm` that I want to use in the meantime, nor will it work if I don't own `bar` or if `bar` is a builtin.)

Comment: You can modify the last `bar` command to `some_command` : `^bar^some_command` before to be executed.

Comment: @GAD3R: but this will not modify current line, it will start a new one.

Answer (score 5):

I've observed that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to shift the program to a background process does the trick.

```
foo && bar
```

Thanks to @Arkadiusz Drabczyk for pointing it in comments that `foo; bar` doesn't give control in the required way.

Then:

```
^Z

[1]+  Stopped                 foo
```

The command stops only the first task and

```
fg %1
```

This brings only task `foo` to the foreground and completes the task and exits.

PS: This can be checked with two scripts writing to a file. The first one sleeping for a few seconds to give time to be put back.

I'm lost on why the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> handles only the command running and leaves the rest. Would love to get to know.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. What `bash` version do you use? I use `GNU
bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)`. I wrote
2 bash scripts that write to different files: `write1.sh`:
https://pastebin.com/rbKmdWgB and `write2.sh`:
https://pastebin.com/bNx3VRws. I run them like that: `./write1.sh ;
./write2.sh`. The first script echoes `wrote 1` for a few times, I
press `C-z`, it says `[1]+ Stopped ./write1.sh` and I can immediately
see output of the second script: `wrote 2` being echoed repeatedly.

Comment: I think the reason that this method works with `command1 && command2`
pipelines is that `Control-z` sends `SIGCHLD`
signal to the process.  It can be checked with `echo $?`. `Bash` then
sees that the first process didn't finish successfully and does not
execute next processes.

Comment: I am using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`.
Yeah, I think you are right. `foo; bar` cannot be controlled in the desired way. But we can do the required stop of the second process with `Ctrl+Z` if the command run is `foo && bar`. I will update the answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk doesn't Ctrl-Z send SIGTSTP?

Comment: @RevanthChetluru note that `bar` is still suspended and shows up in `jobs` output, so it probably should be killed too.

Comment: Confirming that this seems to work for lists delimited with `&&`, but not with `||` or `;`.  So the answer is at least one-third correct. :)  If anyone knows the rest of the answer, please post it!

Comment: @muru: yes, it sends 'SIGTSTP`, sorry I was wrong