# How can I prevent the second command in a chain while keeping the first one running?

Tags: command-line, zsh, shutdown, job-control

Yesterday before going to sleep I started a long process of which I thought it would be finished before I stand up, therefore I used

```bsh
./command && sudo poweroff
```

my system is configured to not ask for a password for `sudo poweroff`, so it should shutdown when that command is finished.

However it is still running and I want to use that system for other tasks now. Having that command running in the background is not an issue, but having my system possibly shutting down any second is.

**Is there a way to prevent `zsh` from executing the `poweroff` command while making sure that the first one runs until it is done?**

Would editing the `/etc/sudoers` file so that the system asks for my password still help in this case?

Comment: Did you start that in an interactive zsh shell as `{ ./command && sudo poweroff; } &` or as part of a zsh script (in a terminal session or not?)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in an interactive shell.

Comment: Was it really put in background or is it still running in foreground in that interactive shell? How did you put it in background?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's not in background. It runs in a terminal in the terminal emulator "Konsole". I can start other programs by opening another tab or another window. I have used `htop` to increase the niceness of the command, so it doesn't interfere with what I'm doing.

Comment: I myself would write a simple C program that runs two command lines. Before running the second command line, the program would wait as long as a file is present. I can prevent the second command from being executed by creating the file.

Comment: This question is a near-duplicate of mine ("[How can I cancel the rest of a list of commands in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434991/37849)"), except that I ask about bash and this question is about zsh.  Still, some of the answers there may be relevant.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you clarified in comments it's still running in foreground on an interactive shell, you should just be able to press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.

That will suspend the `./command` job. Unless `./command` actually intercepts the SIGTSTP signal and chooses to exit(0) in that case (unlikely), the exit status will be non-0 (128+SIGTSTP, generally 148), so `sudo poweroff` will not be run.

Then, you can resume `./command` in foreground or background with `fg` or `bg`.

You can test with:

```
sleep 10 && echo poweroff
```

And see that `poweroff` is not output when you press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> and resume later with `fg`/`bg`.

Or with

```
sleep 10 || echo "failed: $?"
```

And see `failed: 148` as soon as you press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>.

Note that this is valid for `zsh` and assuming you started it with `./command && sudo poweroff`. It may not be valid for other shells, and would not be if you started it some other way such as `(./command && sudo poweroff)` in a subshell or `{ ./command && sudo poweroff; }` as part of a compound command (which `zsh`, contrary to most other shells transforms to a subshell so it can be resumed as a whole when suspended).

Comment: Once the ./command resumes (I assume op wants to finish that task) it will be still attached to the && sudo poweroff, so the problem remains? is there a way to cancel that && command? maybe rename the poweroff command temporarily?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, no it will not, not in `zsh`, that `&& sudo poweroff` will be evaluated at the time `./command` is suspended and the job *returns* the first time with an exit status of 148. It's only if you entered `fg && sudo poweroff` instead of `fg` alone that `sudo poweroff` would be run once `./command` exits successfully (without being suspended again).

Comment: wow, that's highly unexpected... && or || is usually there to ensure the right hand part is done only if the left hand part was complete (and resp exited with 0 or >0). suspending shouldn't change that, it makes little sense (and is counter intuitive). Thanks for the heads up (I usually am happy to use ctrl-z to pause something when needed, but now I will be very worried if the command is complex)

Comment: @OlivierDulac,but if it had to be done like you say, how would the shell handle it? Note that `zsh`'s behaviour is already an improvement on most other shells where when you press Ctrl-Z while a function or compound command is running for instance, it interrupts the whole command and you can resume it later, though that's then done in a subshell, so in a subshell environment which means changes are lost once the interrupted and resumed function returns. Here if you want to be able to stop/resume a chain, you should start it in a subshell.

Comment: And this is why I usually use `&&` when chaining long-running commands (like `cp` or `rsync`) instead of `;`, in case I want to change my mind about what I'm queueing up after this one finishes.

Answer (score 9):

You could just rename /sbin/poweroff temporarily.

Comment: If you were feeling really cheeky, you could rename `/bin/sudo` temporarily. :)

Comment: oh god, thats so dirty - but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent zsh from executing the poweroff command while making sure that the first one runs until it is done?

I don't think it's possible unless you use something like `gdb` to edit the memory of a running process.

> Would editing the /etc/sudoers file so that the system asks for my password still help in this case?

It should help.

Comment: They could always kill the shell process that waits for the `./command` termination. Whether that would affect the running of `./command` would depend on the context.

Comment: That might kill the `./command` as well.

Comment: Possibly, which is what I meant by *Whether that would affect the running of ./command would depend on the context* and why I'm requesting clarifications from the OP. But depending on that context, it's likely it's possible to remove that risk one way or another.